# Get version of MS access database in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using the code below in Excel 365 > Visual Basic Editor to attempt to determine which version of MS Access was used to create an old database. The code works for a newer `.accdb` database I created as a test. As far as I know the older database was originally written/designed in Access 97, but I want to find out for sure.

```
Public Sub GetAccessFormat()
    ' Attempt to determine the format of an Access database
    ' Note: Can Access 16.0 (Office 365) read databases from Office 2013 and earlier?
    On Error GoTo Error_NotAccessDatabase
    Dim fileName As String
    'fileName = "C:\Tmp\old.mdb"  ' Fails
    fileName = "C:\Tmp\new.accdb" ' Works
    
    If IsEmpty(Dir(fileName)) Then
        MsgBox "Could not find: " & fileName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Open the database
    Dim objAccess As Object
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application") ' Is this the problem?
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase fileName
    objAccess.Visible = False
    
    ' Get the file format
    Dim fileFormat As Integer
    fileFormat = objAccess.CurrentProject.FileFormat ' Gets here and fails for .mdb (returns "12" for the .accdb)
    Dim strAccessFormat As String
    strAccessFormat = "Your database is: "
    
    Select Case fileFormat
        Case 2
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2")
        Case 7
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 95")
        Case 8
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 97")
        Case 9
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2000")
        Case 10
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2002")
        Case 11
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2003")
        Case 12
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2007")
        Case 14
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2010")
        Case 15
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2013")
        Case 16
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2016/9")
        Case Else
            strAccessFormat = "Unknown Access file format"
    End Select
    
    ' Close database and display the format information
    objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
    strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat + " (" & fileFormat & ".0)")
    MsgBox strAccessFormat
    Exit Sub

Error_NotAccessDatabase:
    ' Unable to open the database (not Access or not supported by this version of Office?)
    MsgBox "Unable to open as Access database: " & strFile & ", Error: " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The error text is "The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist." (The database does exist, is not open in another application and there is no lock on the database)

We have Office 365 (with Access 16.0) installed, so I assume the problem is with `Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")` because the "Access Application" on my PC will be unable to read older format access databases.

Is this correct? And is there a workaround to determine the file format of old Access databases?

Comment: You don't need to use late bound declaration like that for the host. It's already loaded by nature of you using it. Remove `objAccess ` and replace with simply `Application`

Comment: Note that Access_2013 and newer will absolutely refuse to open .mdb files from Access_97 and earlier.

Comment: @HackSlash: Not sure I follow. `Application` has members like `ActiveCell`, but there is no `CurrentProject` or `FileFormat` member or property.

Comment: @AlainD, see the tested code in my answer. If you're seeing `ActiveCell` then it sounds like you are using Excel. Your tag says `ms-access` so I assumed you were using Access as the host to run the VBA. Please clarify in your question what VBA host you are using if it's not the expected one.

Comment: @HackSlash:Yes Excel...there are other `VBA` hosts other than Microsoft Office products? I did clarify I'm use Office 365, is something missing from the question?

Comment: @AlainD Yes, you can put VBA in to any application. Many engineering software have it. Even within Office 365 you need to be specific about which host you are using because they all have different Application object models with application specific APIs exposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also "peek" at the twenty-first byte of the file and determine its file type from that:

```vb
Function GetAccessFileType(filePath As String) As String
    Dim strm As New ADODB.Stream
    strm.Type = adTypeBinary
    strm.Open
    strm.LoadFromFile filePath
    strm.Read 20
    Dim bytes As Variant
    bytes = strm.Read(1)
    Dim fileTypeNumber As Integer
    fileTypeNumber = CInt(bytes(0))
    strm.Close
    Set strm = Nothing
    Dim fileTypeString As String
    Select Case fileTypeNumber
        Case 0:
            fileTypeString = "Access 97 or older"
        Case 1:
            fileTypeString = "Access 2000/2003"
        Case 2:
            fileTypeString = "Access 2007"
        Case 3:
            fileTypeString = "Access 2010"
        Case 5:
            fileTypeString = "Access 2016 with BIGINT support (Type 5)"
        Case Else:
            fileTypeString = "Unknown (" & fileTypeNumber & ")"
    End Select
    GetAccessFileType = fileTypeString
End Function
```

Comment: This answer is better because it doesn't depend upon Access being able to open the file.

Comment: This works! Except `ADODB` was not recognised in VBA within my version of Excel. So I opened the file with `Binary Access Read` and read the first 21 bytes into a type defined as `Dim buffer() As Byte`. Now `buffer(20)` contains the data file type number.

Answer (score 2):

You generally don't want to use a full fat `Access.Application` object for testing the version, try just using a `DAO.DbEngine` one:

```vb
    ' Open the database
    Dim dbe As Object
    If fileName Like "*.mdb" Then
        Set dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DbEngine.36") 
        'Old JET engine, on 32-bits likely the MDAC version that still supports Access 2.0
    Else
        Set dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DbEngine.120")
        'ACE engine
    End If
    Dim db As Object
    Set db = dbe.OpenDatabase(fileName)
    
    ' Get the file format
    Dim fileFormat As String
    fileFormat = db.Version 'Decode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-version-property-dao
```

Note that both `CurrentProject.FileFormat` and `Database.Version` don't really go beyond 12.0.

We can also attempt to get the more exact version:

```
fileFormat = db.Properties!Version 'Decode = ???
```

However, for this version, I don't have a decoder ready. For an accdb created without recent fields (no bigint/datetime extended), it returns "12.0", which is in line with 2010 features being the most recent used.

However, if I add a datetime extended field, it jumps to "32.0", which is harder to decode, especially since starting with 2016, database features haven't corresponded to major Office releases (early 2016 builds don't support bigint, late 2016 builds do).

Comment: How to use DAO 3.6 in VBA using 64-bit Excel? Adding a reference to `Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library` in my VBA project, resulted in "Error in loading DLL". I discovered that the COM object was registered to `%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll` instead of `%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%`. My efforts to register the DLL manually resulted in no change in the registry, so I opied `dao360.dll` to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO`. Now I can add a reference to `Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library`, but "DAO.DbEngine.36" is still "unrecognised".

Comment: I'd use late binding, for starters. If you're limited to 64-bits Excel, then [use a COM surrogate](https://techtalk.gfi.com/32bit-object-64bit-environment/). Moving a 32-bits DLL to a different folder doesn't suddenly make it work with 64-bits programs, you need the surrogate to translate.

Comment: Wow, just tried that COM surrogate on `dao360.dll` (Windows 10, Excel 365) and it works!

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft:

> Convert an Access 97 database to the .accdb format
>
> Starting with Access 2013, it’s no longer possible to directly convert
> an Access 97 database (.mdb) to the .accdb file format. However, you
> can open an Access 97 database in a previous version of Access, and
> then save the database in a format that Access 2013 can open. For
> example, here’s how to use Access 2003 to open an Access 97 database,
> then convert it to a format that can be opened by Access 2013:
>
> 1. Open the Access 97 database in Access 2003.
> 2. Click Tools > Database Utilities > Convert Database > to Access
>    2002-2003 file format.
> 3. Enter a name for the database and click Save.
> 4. Close Access 2003 and open Access 2013.
> 5. Open the database and click File > Save As > Access Database
>    (.accdb) > Save As > Save.
>
> You can also use Access 2007 or Access 2010 to convert an Access 97
> database to the .accdb format. When you open an Access 97 database in
> either of these two products, the Database Enhancement wizard appears
> to help convert the database to an .accdb format.

**SOURCE:** https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-a-database-to-the-accdb-file-format-098ddd31-5f84-4e89-8f44-db0cf7c11acd#__convert_an_access

**ALTERNATE SOLUTION:**

If you don't have an old version of Access and want to pull the data out you can do so using any modern Excel version using the import function found on the Data tab. Once you have the data saved out to Excel you can import it back in to Access from Excel.

**TESTED CODE:**

All that said, here is a tested version of your code that works with any DB that Access can open:

```
Public Sub GetAccessFormat()
    ' Attempt to determine the format of an Access database
    On Error GoTo Error_NotAccessDatabase
    Dim fileName As String
    'fileName = "C:\Tmp\old.mdb"  ' Fails
    fileName = "C:\Tmp\new.accdb" ' Works
    
    If IsEmpty(Dir(fileName)) Then
        MsgBox "Could not find: " & fileName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Open the database
    Application.OpenCurrentDatabase fileName
    Application.Visible = False
    
    ' Get the file format
    Dim strAccessFormat As String
    strAccessFormat = "Your database is: "
    
    Select Case Application.CurrentProject.FileFormat
        Case acFileFormatAccess2
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2")
        Case acFileFormatAccess95
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 95")
        Case acFileFormatAccess97
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 97")
        Case acFileFormatAccess2000
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2000")
        Case acFileFormatAccess2002
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2002")
        Case 11
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2003")
        Case 12
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2007")
        Case 14
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2010")
        Case 15
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2013")
        Case 16
            strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat & "Microsoft Access 2016/9")
        Case Else
            strAccessFormat = "Unknown Access file format"
    End Select
    
    ' Close database and display the format information
    strAccessFormat = (strAccessFormat + " (" & Application.CurrentProject.FileFormat & ".0)")
    MsgBox strAccessFormat
    
    Application.CloseCurrentDatabase
    Exit Sub

Error_NotAccessDatabase:
    ' Unable to open the database (not Access or not supported by this version of Office?)
    MsgBox "Unable to open as Access database: " & fileName & ", Error: " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Great answer...but unfortunately fails in Excel 365. The error is `Object doesn't support this property or method`. My `Application` object does not have a `OpenCurrentDatabase` method...

Comment: ( cc: @AlainD ) - The [Access 2010 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=10910) appears to still be available for download. I tried it once to convert an Access 97 database to something newer and it seemed to work okay for me. (Unfortunately, I don't remember the details.)

Comment: @AlainD, this is an Access question so I gave you an Access answer. Why are you opening Access from Excel? Just do it in Access.

Comment: Access 365 (Access 16.0) won't open old .mdf files...

Comment: @AlainD right, so use the built-in data import feature of Excel. No VBA is needed. It will import the data in to your workbook.